# Why does the defroster make the windshield even more foggy at first?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, states-of-matter

I have noticed that sometimes when I use the defroster, at first the windshield becomes even more foggy, almost impossible to see through. Then, after a while the defroster starts having effect  and the windshield becomes easy to see through. This happens even with a warmed up engine.

So it seems as if in the beginning the defroster has the opposite effect of what it is made for.

The temperature outside is about 55F. Just for clarification, I am not asking why this would happen when you just start the car, this happens even when the car has already been running for a while. The defroster is set on warm air.

Question:

1. Why does the defroster make the windshield even more foggy at first?

Comment: Does it occur in a specific time of the day? In case it was morning: Did your car stand in a garage over night? Was the sky cloudy? If no, your car might have lost considerable amount of heat to space as nothing blocked radiation from your car. Additionally for how long was the motor running already. Does the defroster already provide warm air? And is the temperature within the car also considerably larger than outside? In case the temperature inside is lower, warm air from outside contains more moist which condensates on the windshield in the first place.

Comment: @BenjaminFeldern yes the car has been running already for a long time, the engine is warm. This happens already when I am driving the car around in the rain even for hours. Yes the air coming from the defroster is warm.

Comment: There is moisture collecting in your vents, the defroster blows the moisture onto the cold glass creating the fog until the defroster warms the glass.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban you would like to write it as an answer?

Comment: No, it was really a comment that the fog your seeing is due to moisture blowing on the glass from the defroster. I don't know where the moisture is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that the defrost function requires that both the *heater* (which runs on hot water from the engine) *and the air conditioner* (which is used to dehumidify the air) to be on at the same time. It always takes a minute or so for the air conditioner to come fully on-line and during that time the defrost air is not being dehumidified, and the de-misting process can't get started.

Comment: Thank you so much!